# Como ativar o VirtualEnv no prompt de comando do Windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

No Linux eu consigo executando

```
. bin/activate
```

Tentei o mesmo comando no Windows, mas não funcionou. Como faço para ativar o virtualenv no Windows?

Comment: Olá, Ana. Importante [edit] sua pergunta e fornecer um [mcve]. Veja também o  [Guia rápido sobre como fazer perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Quando você cria o VirtualEnv pelo Windows, a estrutura de pastas criada será:

```
D:\projeto\venv
│   pyvenv.cfg
│
├───Include
│       ...
├───Lib
|       ...
└───Scripts
        activate
        activate.bat
        Activate.ps1
        deactivate.bat
        easy_install-3.9.exe
        easy_install.exe
        pip.exe
        pip3.9.exe
        pip3.exe
        python.exe
        pythonw.exe
```

Ou seja, o caminho que tentou executar, `bin/activate`, não existirá. Mesmo se existisse não funcionaria, pois esse arquivo possui instruções para a configuração de ambientes Linux.

No Windows, você pode utilizar o arquivo `activate.bat` ou ainda o `activate.ps1` se estiver utilizando o PowerShell.

**Exemplo:**

```
D:\projeto> .\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1
(venv) D:\projeto>
```